# Remove Image or video file from folder after 7 days with PHP

Tags: php, cron

I have lots of images and videos on a sub-folder of a particular user-id folder.

I have a `save` and `update` dates and one more - `expiry` date, which is the `update` date + 7 days within the database.

After 7 days this file needs to be automatically removed from the folder and deleted from the database.

What's the code in PHP for this?

Comment: show your code and what you have tried??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a "cronjob" which searches your database for the files that need to be deleted, and then use the [`unlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function to delete the files.

Comment: Yes, its a good, i want to use code without cron job, because i have only FTP detail of Website.

Comment: Well you'll need to create a cronjob on another server to then login by FTP and delete those files.

Comment: thanks, but i have alternative idea, create a php code in root folder and check every request from client, and run this code is common way.

Comment: That would work - but it will make your site very slow.

Comment: Yes, but my server use only for web service,  i have work on android and Iphone application and store data in web server using webapi, so not more loading...